# Is there a parameter to allow drivers to jostle from an empty lane to a busy lane on Eclipse SUMO

Tags: sumo

I'm simulating drivers with Eclipse SUMO using TraCi. I have a road segment of 1Km (highway) that contains five lanes: two right lanes that are leading to a right turn (exit), and three left lanes that are leading straight. It seems that drivers that want to go right will stand on the right lanes regardless of the queue size, resulting in two lanes that are very slow, and beside them, three lanes that can have a speed of 120 Km/h.

In reality, some drivers are not waiting in the 1 Km queue, but deciding to jostle to the queue in the middle, while other might regret standing in the queue and decide to go straight instead. This is resulting in a slow down on the three left lanes i.e., it is rare to have two adjacent lanes
(lanes 2 and 3 from the right on this case) with a 100 km/h speed difference (safety reasons)

My question is if a parameter that limits the speed ratio between two adjacent lanes exists, or if there is another way to simulate this kind of behavior, as I could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different behaviors you propose as alternative to standing in the queue. The first one is changing the lane later which you might achieve by reducing the eagerness to do a strategic lane change with the [`lcStrategic` parameter](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Definition_of_Vehicles%2C_Vehicle_Types%2C_and_Routes.html#lane-changing_models).

The second idea is to change the route and/or the destination. To change the route automatically you can enable the [rerouting device for the vehicles](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Demand/Automatic_Routing.html). This will work only if there really is a faster route (taking the jam into account) in your network which leads to the same destination. Another possibility is to employ [rerouters](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Rerouter.html) to set new routes or destinations. You can define a probability here but it is not possible to let this depend on the size / delay of the jam .